# Camera zoom in Intel XDK

Tags: three.js, intel-xdk

I'm creating a simple mobile apps using Intel XDK and ThreeJS. The problem is, I do not know how to zoom the object after the other object is being clicked, (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

One way to zoom into an ThreeJS object is with the jQuery plugin, [Zoomooz.js](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/).

Here is an example.

http://jsbin.com/juril/1/edit?html,js,output

This example is based on the [Threejs Dashed lines example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_lines_dashed.html). I have added the following attributes to the two dashed boxes.

```
<div class="zoomViewport">
            <div class="zoomContainer">
                <div class="zoomTarget" data-targetsize="2.0" data-closeclick="true" id="container"></div>
                <p></p>
                <div class="zoomTarget" data-targetsize="2.0" data-closeclick="true"  id="container2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This allows you to zoom into each box at two times the magnification with one click/touch as well as zoom out with one click/touch.

You can also pinch to zoom since I commented out the following  tag.

```
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">-->
```